# Translating a NodeJS heap dump to the code leaking memory

Tags: node.js, heap-memory

I've got a NodeJS application that has a memory leak.  (Obviously what I mean is that somewhere, references are not being released so objects can't be garbage collected.)

I've taken various heap snapshots and am looking at them in Chrome's dev tools.

However, presumably due to the structure of the app, there's apparently nothing in the heap dump that allows me to identify where the issue exists.

Examples I've seen all show specific class names in the heap dump, but all I'm getting listed in the Constructor column is stuff like "Object" and "system / Context".  It seems that everything taking up significant space in the heap is a general, could-be-anywhere object.

Some objects have a very large "Distance", which I understand means there's a long chain of references keeping them from being garbage-collected, so I've been focussing particularly on those.  Unfortunately, all I can glean is that they're a bunch of "system / WeakCell" objects.  And googling for that returns only [one hit](https://gist.github.com/syg), which is just a diff showing when the string was added to the profiler.

The image below shows the kind of thing I'm getting.  It's all very anonymous, so I can't work out how I'm supposed to deduce from the heap dump what object or what part of the code (mine or a library) is causing the problem.

[image: The kind of thing I'm getting]

I suppose I was naively hoping that I could inspect values on the heap so I could see precisely what's there, thus leading me to the relevant section of code!

I've been searching for days now and can only find things that say how to generate heap dumps or how to see the difference between two dumps - but every time, the examples seem to have specific JavaScript objects mentioned in the dumps!  I've got nothing like that.

Is there some clever way of reading the heap dump in Chrome (or something else) that will point me at the code that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help without anything else. The object you display has an abort function on it and a signal. Do they all do? Try to find objects that get assigned those properties in your code. Also, try to open the **proto** this may reveal some more clues too.

Keep in mind that this could come from third party libraries too. In this case, it will get even more complicated. You'll have to comment out parts of your code, hopefully you have an idea of what/when the memory gets clogged up like that.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a bit! :-)  Digging down into the prototype for the one opened in the top pane shows that it's an Object, but then digging down further shows (apparently) that it's actually a Function.  This makes me wonder (again) whether I've got functions that call themselves but never finally return...  They aren't _all_ like that, by the way: I've dug down and some have different properties (there's one which looks like a map of file extensions to their MIME types, for example).